# How to Slide pages automatically in ViewPager Android

Tags: android

I have 4 images in `ViewPager` and I want to slide all these images one by one And after 4th images, I want to show the 1st image.following code shows the automatic slide page,but stop after 4th image.

```
            switchtimer= new Timer();
            switchtimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Log.v("TimerMtd", "Timer call");
                    handler.post(Update);
                }
            }, 1500,3000);
        }
    Handler handler = new Handler();

    Runnable Update = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            mPager.setCurrentItem(currentpage);
            currentpage++;
            if(currentpage > 2){
                currentpage = 0;
                Log.v("TimerMtd", currentpage+"cutrrentpage =");
             }

            }
    };
```

Comment: plz suggest if any alternative

Comment: Hi Patle, How are you?

Comment: Kya patle kuch to reply de diya kar agar ye tu hai to.

Comment: Abey tu Pradip patle from Tumsar hi hai na, staying at JuiNagar, Mumbai..??

Comment: Kya baat hai patle, 5 points badha gaye lagata hai tere Stack Overflow k.?? Ab thanks mat bolna... :-)

Answer (score 1):

I have made some methods to do the same, got refrence from one of the SO answer but not remembering that right now, below is the code i am using :

```
Timer timer;
int page = 0;

public void pageSwitcher(int seconds) {
    timer = new Timer(); // At this line a new Thread will be created
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new RemindTask(), 0, seconds * 1000); // delay
    // in
    // milliseconds
}

// this is an inner class...
class RemindTask extends TimerTask {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        // As the TimerTask run on a seprate thread from UI thread we have
        // to call runOnUiThread to do work on UI thread.
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                if (page > 5) { // In my case the number of pages are 5
                    page = 0;
                } else {
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(page);
                    page++;
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

and in `onCreate()` i call this method like this

```
 pageSwitcher(3); // Here "3" is delay in seconds
```